# Html script src files that are linked to each other

Tags: javascript, html

(simplification) I have two javascript files I want to include. They inter-link each other.

Problem: If I just include them the following there is an error because source1.js needs something from source2.js and vice-versa.

**How can I include inter-linking source files properly in HTML, without merging them?** (Imaging various already-large files)

```
<head>
<script src="source1.js"></script>
<script src="source2.js"></script>
```

*source1.js*

```
function filtersomething() {
    ...
    othersource.somefunction();
}
```

*source2.js*

```
var columns = {
    text: filtersomething()
}
```

Comment: Both scripts should wait until the DOM is loaded. You can then check with `typeof` if an object / function from the other file exists. Alternatively use a [function pointer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) as parameter for `filtersomething`.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I can tell you that source1.js wants "whatever" in source2.js and because it's loaded first, "whatever" is not available... https://i.imgur.com/L7WTx3R.png (Screenshot from my Chrome Console showing the error)

Comment: Update your question with error messages, don't hide it in a comment. Also: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Added more to a working snippet.  I'd use that code over some of the examples here.  it deals more with arguments, promises, etc.  Have to run, hope this helps.

You can place an event listener within each JS file, which would not call any functions until the dom is loaded.  Doing this allows both JS files to load in and see the others functions available.

```
// script.js

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    filtersomething();
});
function filtersomething() {
    ...
    othersource.somefunction();
}
```

Because these are loaded after script.js, script2.js always sees what script.JS has available.  So, script.JS does not see what script2.JS has until after it is loaded

```js
// script2.js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var columns = {
      text: filtersomething()
    }
});
```

We can also watch for a pointer, as suggested.  This is useful when waiting for jQuery to load as well. So within your script files, watch for a property to be set, then execute.

```html
<head>
    <script>
        function deferRun(thisMethod, scriptNum) {
            if (window[scriptNum])
                return thisMethod();
            // No property found, set timeout of 50ms and try again
            setTimeout(function() { defer(thisMethod, scriptNum) }, 50);     
        }
    </script>
    <script src="source1.js"></script>
    <script src="source2.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
// script2.JS
// wait until script.js is available, then return result
var columns = {
  text: deferRun(filtersomething, 'script1')
}

// Set our window property saying script loaded
window.script2 = true;
```

```
//script.js 

function filtersomething() {
    ...
    deferRun(othersource.somefunction, 'script2');
}
// Set our window property saying script loaded
window.script1 = true;
```

```js
// Think of script1/script2 as <script> tags. 
window.script1 = {
  // script.js
  filtersomething: () => {
    return deferRun('somefunction', 'script2', 'message to use');
  }
};

// Now "load" script2.js
window.script2 = {
  somefunction: (msg) => {
    return `msg response is ${msg}`
  },
  columns: {
    // wait until script.js is available, then return result
    text: deferRun('filtersomething', 'script1')
  },
  render: async() => {
    console.log(await window.script2.columns.text);
  }
};


(async() => {
  await window.script2.render();
})();
```

````html
<head>
  <script>
    // this is available to all and before either script 1 or 2 loads
    function deferRun(thisMethod, property, argument = null) {
      if (window[property])
        return window[property][thisMethod](argument);
      // No property found, set timeout of 50ms and try again
      return setTimeout(function() {
        deferRun(thisMethod, property, argument)
      }, 50);
    }
  </script>
</head>
You can place an event listener within each JS file, which would not call any functions until the dom is loaded. Doing this allows both JS files to load in and see the others functions available.

<pre>
// script.js

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    filtersomething();
});
function filtersomething() {
    ...
    othersource.somefunction();
}
```

Because these are loaded after script.js, script2.js always sees what script.JS has available.  So, script.JS does not see what script2.JS has until after it is loaded 

```js
// script2.js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var columns = {
      text: filtersomething()
    }
});
```

We can also watch for a pointer, as suggested.  This is useful when waiting for jQuery to load as well. So within your script files, watch for a property to be set, then execute.

</pre>
````